# Reading xls file content from user on button click

Tags: java, excel, jsp

I want to allow user to upload xlsx file. which will be in particular format.

Then I want to read the content of xls file and want to insert into database.

Here I took absolute file path to read and insert the data.

How can I read file from user and do the action which I have performed?

```
public class upload {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Myconnection con = new Myconnection();
        Statement stmt = null;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/upload.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator ite = sheet.rowIterator();

        //PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into ParcelCoordinates(Subdivision,ParcelNo,PointID,Easting,Northing,Height) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        String prepStmt = "insert into ParcelCoordinates(RequestID,SubdivisionNo,ParcelNo,PointID,Easting,Northing,Height) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(prepStmt); 

...remaining code 

}
```

I put submit button and on button click user upload the file

```
<form:form action="" modelAttribute="uploadFile" name="uploadRequest">      
                    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <button onClick = "downloadTemplate()"  style="width:250px" type="submit" class="admin_search_btn"><spring:message code="lblDownloadXls"></spring:message></button>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >
                        <form:input path="fileName" style="width:200px" class="admin_search_btn" type="file" name="uploadxls" value="" />
                        <!-- <input style="width:200px" class="admin_search_btn" type=file name="uploadxls" value=""  /> -->
                    </div>
                    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >  
                        <button onClick = "uploadTemplate()" type="submit" class="admin_search_btn"><spring:message code="lblSubmit"></spring:message></button>&nbsp;
                        <button  type="submit" class="admin_search_btn"><spring:message code="lblCancel"></spring:message></button>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

Now how can I read user uploaded file?

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files for spring or you can try pure servlet http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html

Comment: What is your problem : upload a file, read it in a controller, or get data from a xlsx file ?

Answer (score -1):

this link will show you how to trigger actions on click: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/swing/jbutton.shtml

Since xls its a text file you can read it with:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/upload.xlsx"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // process the line.
}
br.close();
```

in the process line you can do splits and replaces in order to get what you want.

Comment: Are you really sure that xlsx it a text file ??? **csv files are text files, not xls nor xlsx** !